# why does np.vectorize work here when np.where throws a TypeError?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, vector

I have a pandas DataFrame where a column called myenum has values of either 0, 1, or 2.  I am trying to translate 1s and 2s to strings and use an Enum's .name attribute to help.

I think this is a question about understanding the guts of np.where vs np.vectorize as they relate to DataFrame Series.  I am curious why the attempt throws an error using np.where, yet works using np.vectorize.  I would like to learn from this and better understand best vectorization practices in DataFrames.

```
import enum
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame() # one column in this df is 'myenum', its values are either 0, 1, or 2
df['myenum'] = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0]


class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    First = 1
    Second = 2

# this throws a TypeError - why?
df['myenum'] = np.where(
    df['myenum'] > 0,
    MyEnum(df['myenum']).name,
    ''
    )

# whereas this, which seems pretty analagous, works.  what am i missing?
def vectorize_enum_value(x):
    if x > 0:
        return  MyEnum(x).name
    return ''
vect = np.vectorize(vectorize_enum_value)
df['myenum'] = vect(df['myenum'])
```

Comment: `MyEnum(df['myenum']).name` can't ever work.  The `MyEnum` constructor is not part of `numpy` or `pandas`, and has no idea what to do when passed an array.   You do need either `vectorize` or `apply` here.

Comment: @Tim Roberts thanks - so the lesson is, to use np.where, you must only perform operations inside the where clause that numpy knows how to do?  that makes sense.  and vectorize is a valid workaround, likely faster than apply (though consider testing that?).  thanks.

Comment: Basically, yes.  `numpy` and `pandas` objects and functions know how to deal with vectors and arrays, but you have to use things like apply and vectorize to get "non-aware" functions in there.

Comment: thanks.  maybe a more specific lesson would be "only perform operations inside the where call *on the array* that numpy knows how to do".  i qualify with *on the array* because in looking at some of my other working np.where usage, i do often bring in my own classes, but with your help i realize i've never passed my classes an array ...

Comment: `np.where` is only as good as the `cond` argument: `df['myenum'] > 0`.  In Python, function arguments are evaluate first, and then passed to the function.  `where` is not an iterator or 'magic'.  I was going to write a full answer with demonstration, but you haven't provided a valid dataframe.  `np.vectorize` isn't particularly fast; it's like a list comprehension. But `pandas.apply` is very slow, unless your specify the `raw` mode.

Comment: @10mjg there is no "where clause", `np.where` is a *function* not a statement.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks- fwiw i actually thought i caught that misnomer and edited it out already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **full traceback** from your `where` expression is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 641, in __new__
    return cls._value2member_map_[value]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-27-16f5edc71240>", line 3, in <module>
    MyEnum(df['myenum']).name,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 339, in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 648, in __new__
    if member._value_ == value:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1537, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

It's produced by giving the **whole** series to `MyEnum`:

```
In [30]: MyEnum(df['myenum'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 641, in __new__
    return cls._value2member_map_[value]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
...
```

The problem isn't with the `where` at all.

The `where` works fine if we provide it with a valid list of strings:

```
In [33]: np.where(
    ...:     df['myenum'] > 0,
    ...:     [vectorize_enum_value(x) for x in df['myenum']],
    ...:     ''
    ...:     )
Out[33]: 
array(['', 'First', 'Second', '', '', '', 'Second', 'First', ''],
      dtype='<U6')
```

That 2nd argument, the list comprehension is basically the same as the `vectorize`.

`where` is a function; Python evaluates function arguments before passing them in.  So each argument has to work.  `where` is **not** an iterator, like `apply` or even `vectorize`.